# Why does my Internet feel so slow when Speedtest.net reports 55Mbps down?

Tags: internet

[image]

I have fibre Internet from BT, but when I browse the Internet (in Chrome or Firefox, on Windows 7 or Linux Mint), images and pages take a while to load (a lot longer than would be expected considering the download speed).

Large sequential downloads such as disk images and movies will max out my powerline networking at about 60mbps

Comment: Could you describe how the device you are using is connected to the internet, is it plugged in directly into the powerline wall plug or using wireless (and if so, the powerline wireless or the BT router wireless)? Also at the other end is the output from the BT router plugged into another powerline wall plug, etc.

Comment: Fibre -> BT Fibre modem -> Ethernet to BT Home Hub Router -> Ethernet to powerline wall socket -> MAGIC -> Ethernet to my Realtek network interface on my motherboard

Comment: I don't know what you consider slow, but download speed has not much to do with your browsing (basicly it has up to 2-5 mbps more or less).  It much depends on your browser, hard disk i/o speed, and of course of the site you try to open (not being optimised, writing your details to database and waiting for response or sending a url and waiting for response to third party like google analytics..)

Comment: +1 for "MAGIC" 8-). Have you tried using a different DNS provider than BT (such as http://www.opennicproject.org/ others are available). There is always going to be a minimum amount of time due to hard drive speed/CPU/RAM/blah which "internet speed" won't improve. How is the speed when directly plugged into the Ethernet to BT Home Hub Router?

Comment: A good DNS speed test is here: https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: Alternatively, BT might be traffic shaping you as well, the rotters...

Comment: You say you have fiber, but not what your upload speed limit is. I assume it's high enough, maybe even symmetrical. With many DSL lines where limits are assymmetrical (low max upload speed) all the TCP/IP confirmations going back up can seriously degrade download performance (Read e.g. http://phix.me/dm/)

Comment: You don't happen to have AVG antivirus do you? This has some sort of 'look-ahead' feature (I forgot its name) that actually starts following links on downloaded pages *before* you request them (you may not even actually request them at all). This was a pipeline hog when we were developing internet filters ;-(

Comment: And I would seriously investigate what other software on your side could be intercepting the in- and outgoing data streams. Your browser is a different environment than the speedtest program.

Comment: SpeedTest.net gives the speed in Megabits(Mb) and not MegaBytes(MB). People often overlook this given we are used to talking in Bytes. Hence the speed you would otherwise expect gets divided by 8.

Answer (score 2):

Speedtest is just a report of how much *bandwidth* you have, max theoretical download speed, not necessarily the *practical* throughput, which is what you want. Consider this:

> The computer on the other end typically ***does not*** have an upload speed that matches your download speed.

You can only ***pull*** as fast as the other person can ***push***. Also, there are many factors at work that dictate your ***true*** internet speed. Accessing an arbitrary speed server for purposes of verifying speed is different from accessing Willy's Weary Websites (3x times fast) hosted in someone's basement (worst case example), you're going to notice a difference in webspeed pertaining to

1)***Your*** bandwidth speed

2)The ***other person's*** bandwidth speed

3)***Everything in the middle***

Yes, ISP companies beef up their advertisements for the sake of sales. This info doesn't get bigger sales.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually aware of how this stuff works, I just phrased my question is a specificly non-technical manner, to see if I there was anything blatently obvious that I missed. imgur.com is a good example of a site on which images load very slowly. They have plenty of bandwidth.

Comment: @blazemore they have milions and milions of visitors sharing that bandwith at once

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my internet connection while my download was 50Mbps:
If your DNS lookup is slow you'll not have much use of an high download speed, because converting the URL address into an ip takes too long.
This is not the problem with big downloads like an .iso or a movie because the URL gets converted only once. But when you have a website with many images, scripts, etc... you'll notice a big difference.

Comment: The result of the DNS lookup is cached, so the lookup delay will only influence the time it takes to access the website for the first time. The loading time - especially for a website with lots of embedded media - will then depend on your connection's bandwidth and latency.

Comment: @n.st Same thing for me: reloading the website is pretty fast but googling and loading new sites is slow.

Comment: Here is a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11026065/470749